# Using elvis/ternary operator as an argument to a function

Tags: conditional-operator, elvis-operator

Let's say I have this block of code in Groovy:

```
String x
String y = "hello"

def func(String str){
   println(str)
}

func(x ?: y)
```

Is there anything wrong with using Elvis operator as an argument to a function like I did above? I tested it and it works as expected, however, I've never seen Elvis operator to be passed to a function like that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've never seen Elvis operator to be passed to a function

Contrary to what your intuition is telling you, you're not seeing it here either.  The operator isn't passed to the function.  The *result* of the *expression* is.

This expression evaluates to a result:

```
x ?: y
```

The result of this expression is a `String` value.  That `String` value is passed to the function.  It doesn't matter to the function how that `String` value was produced before it was passed to the function.